# Doubt about the right way to write an $2-$form

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces

Currently I'm studying Darling's book $[1]$ on differential forms. Now a annoying thing is bothering me. The dimension of wedge space is given by:

$$\mathrm{dim}\big[\Lambda^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\big] := \frac{n!}{(n-p)!p!} \tag{1}$$

So, suppose I want to write and $2-$form in an $4-$dimensional space. Then, I need four covetors as basis $\mathcal{B} = \{\mathrm{d}x^{1},\mathrm{d}x^{2},\mathrm{d}x^{3},\mathrm{d}x^{4}\}$, to form the basis of wedge space $\mathcal{B}^{\Lambda^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{4})}$. Furthermore, the dimension of this wedge space is $6$.

Now, I wrote the $2-$form as:

$$\omega = A \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + B \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + C \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4} +$$

$$+D \mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{1} + E\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + F\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4}+$$

$$+G \mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{1} + H\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + I\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4}+$$

$$+J \mathrm{d}x^{4}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{1} + K\mathrm{d}x^{4}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + L\mathrm{d}x^{4}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} \tag{2}$$

But, since we have the property:

$$\mathrm{d}x^{a}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{b} = -\mathrm{d}x^{b}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{a}$$

I think I suppose to write the $2-$form as:

$$\omega = (A-D) \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + (B-G) \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + (C-J) \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4} +$$

$$+ (E-H)\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + (F-K)\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4}+ (I-L)\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4} \tag{3}$$

Now, suppose that someone gives you an form like:

$$\omega' = f \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{2} + g \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + h \mathrm{d}x^{1}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4} +$$

$$+ i\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{3} + j\mathrm{d}x^{2}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4}+ k\mathrm{d}x^{3}\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{4}$$

I suspect that is incorrect to state that the functions $f,g,h,i,j,k$ have the form:

$$\begin{cases}f = (a-b)\\ g = (c-d)\\ h=(e-t)\\ i=(q-u)\\j=(w-z)\\k = (r-s)\end{cases}$$
**I would like to know then, how I suppose to write the $2-$form? As $(2)$ or $(3)$?**

$$ * * * $$

$[1]$ DARLING.R.W.R. *Differential Forms and Connections.*

Comment: Both are valid expressions, but $\{dx^i\wedge dx^j\}_{i\neq j}$ is not a basis, while $\{dx^i\wedge dx^j\}_{i<j}$ is.

Comment: You can write the functions $f,g,h,i,j,k$ in the form you suggested. Just take $b=d=t=u=z=s=0$ and set $a=f$, $c=g$, $e=h$, $q=i$, $w=j$, and r=k$.